# How should one assign data randomly to cross validation folds?

Tags: cross-validation

For example, in 10-fold cross validation, should one randomly draw an integer (with uniform probability) between 1-10 for each data point, or should you make up a vector of fold indices of equal length to the data, and randomly permute them? In the latter case, what do you do if the number of data points is not divisible by 10?

Answer (score 1):

The latter is better because it guarantees your folds are of equal size (or within one row of equal).

In the case of not being divisible by ten then having some folds be one record smaller is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Lets denote a discrete uniform RV in $[10*(i-1),10*i],i=1,2,...,k$ by $x^{(i)},i=1,2,...,k$ where we assume $n/10=k$ and $n$ is total number of observations, both integers. On the same way we denote a RV from DUNIF(0,n) by $y$ where again $n$ is the total number of observations.

Let do randomizations.

1- in the first one we sample one observation from each $x^{(i)},i=1,2,...,k$. then repeating $k$ times to get samples which are assigned to the test(validation) set.

2- in the second one we select $k$ samples from $y$ and assign them to the test set.

The first one is equivalent to sampling 10 times from $x^{(1)}$. That is you are sampling from $x^{(1)}+10*(i-1),i=1,2,...,k$. the second one is k samples directly from $y\sim DUNIF(0,n)$. Notice that uniform distribution is consistence with respect to the change in location. As a result, both methods are the same.

But in actions, the first one is heavier in term of running by a computer as it needs three steps,
1) dividing data into folds, 2)sampling from folds (a loop) and storing the result.
But the second one needs two steps,
1)sampling from data,2)storing data.

Note that if $k$ is not an integer the second strategy is better, obviousely.